# ASP.NET MVC Creating a variable which contains a list per user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my web app, I have a table `Employees` with Columns for `Employees ID` and their `siteID`. (There are a lot more columns in this table)

I have another table called `SitesPerEmployee` which only has two column `EmployeeID` and `SiteID` which I used to grant access for logged in user so they can only see info based on Sites they are given access to within this table which may be multiple sites per employee, hence the creation of this table.

So Here is my code:

```
string name = Session["Name"].ToString();
var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID);
var des = (from c in db.SitesPerEmployees where c.EmployeeID = EmployeeIDCatch select c.SiteID);
var employeesSearch = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Where(e => e.SiteID = des);
```

I need it so the variable `employeeSearch` will only contain employees with SiteID the same as the logged in user's access which is given in the `SitesPerEmployee` table

Right now I am getting two Errors. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int'` in the code`where c.EmployeeID = EmployeeIDCatch` and  `e.SiteID = des`

Comment: you haven't said, but I'd guess `e.SiteID = des` is the bit giving you the problem? Can you clarify?

Comment: Apologies but yes and also `where c.EmployeeID = EmployeeIDCatch ` both giving the same error. I know it's because Im trying to compare a list of EmployeeIDs to a single one. Is there a workaround perhaps?

Comment: Have you looked at using [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)

Comment: You need to use **`==`** instead of **`=`** here: `where c.EmployeeID == EmployeeIDCatch`. This is apart from other errors. The single `=` is also present in the last line but there you need to use `.Contains` as per Answers below.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks, I'm relatively at c# and I am somewhat confused when to use  `==` and `=`

Comment: The `=` operator is for assignment, the result of it is whatever value or object was assigned. The `==` operator is for comparing values or objects, the result is always a boolean (which is precisely what `where` and `.Where()` need).

Comment: Okay, cool! that clears up a lot of confusion, thanks Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns `IQueryable<int>` instead of `int`:

```
var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID);
```

What you should do is using `SingleOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefault()` to get scalar value:

```
// this query returns int value
var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).Select(s => s.EmployeeID).SingleOrDefault();

// returns multiple SiteIDs
var des = (from c in db.SitesPerEmployees where c.EmployeeID == EmployeeIDCatch select c.SiteID);

var employeesSearch = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Where(e => des.Contains(e.SiteID));
```

As an alternative for first query you can use this:

```
var EmployeeIDCatch = db.Employees.Where(s => s.Email.Equals(name)).FirstOrDefault().EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Using the `Where(e => des.Contains(e.SiteID))` does solve one error, but the first two lines now give new errors  `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'HolidayTracker.Models.Employee' `and `'Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'`

Comment: I realized that `SingleOrDefault()` method wrongly positioned in the previous code. Check the edit if it returns proper scalar `int` value instead of `HolidayTracker.Models.Employee`.

Comment: Yes the errors have gone, but when I run I get a new error `Sequence contains more than one element`. Will this code ensure employeeSearch can contain multiple sites which have been inputed in the `SitesPerEmployee` table. Maybe that where this error is coming from??

Comment: Maybe you should try `FirstOrDefault()` if the query result has more than one element.

Comment: Yep!! Works Perfect now!! Thank you Tetsuya for the help!!

Answer (score 5):

You are getting error because you are comparing list of integers (des) with single integer (SiteID) at `.Where(e => e.SiteID = des);`.

you can do it like:

```
var employeesSearch = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Area).Include(e => e.Discipline).Include(e => e.Shift).Include(e => e.Site).Where(e => des.Contains(e.SiteID));
```